# No repetir números aleatorios

Tags: php, random

he de realizar un código en PHP que cree una tabla y la rellene de valores aleatorios sin repetir. Este es el código que he realizado:

```
<?php
/**
 * Tabla que muestre numeros aleatorios comprendidos entre 1 y 49.
 * La tabla tiene 5 filas y 7 columnas.
 */
    $posicion=0;
    $repetidos=array();

    echo "<table>";
        for($fila=1; $fila<=5 ; $fila++){
            echo "<tr>";
                for($columna=1; $columna<=7; $columna++){
                    echo "<td>" . $repetidos[$posicion]=comprobarRepetido($repetidos,rand(1,49)) . "</td>";
                    $posicion=$posicion+1;
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";

    /**
     * Algoritmo que recorre el contenido de un array
     * y comprueba si el numero pasado por parametros
     * se encuentra contenido en este.
     */
    function comprobarRepetido($array, $numero){
        //bandera para comprobar si el numero se repite
        $repetido=false;

        //recorre el array mientras el valor no esté contenido
        for($indice=0; $indice<count($array) && $repetido==false; $indice++){
            //si el numero es igual a $valor, devuelve true
            $repetido=($array[$indice]==$numero)?true:false;
        }

        //en caso que el numero se repita, pasa por parametros un nuevo numero
        //y realiza recursividad a si misma 
        if($repetido==true)
            comprobarRepetido($array,rand(1,49));
        else
            return $numero;
    }
    ?>
```

El problema es que deja posiciones sin rellenar, y se muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien puede saber por qué pasa esto? He estado viendo casos similares en otros códigos con otro lenguaje, pero usan métodos ya creados.

Comment: Como se llaman los métodos que has visto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que cuando encuentras un numero repetido no estas retornando nada.  Intenta cambiar tu codigo a esto:

```
if($repetido==true)
    return comprobarRepetido($array,rand(1,49));
else
    return $numero;
```

Comment: Efectivamente, era simplemente añadir un return!!; ¿entonces seguiría llamando usando recursividad hasta que $repetido sea false?

Comment: Correcto mi estimado.